# How to force SQL Server to process CONTAINS clauses before WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a SQL query that uses both standard WHERE clauses and full text index CONTAINS clauses. The query is built dynamically from code and includes a variable number of WHERE and CONTAINS clauses.

In order for the query to be fast, it is very important that the full text index be searched before the rest of the criteria are applied.

However, SQL Server chooses to process the WHERE clauses before the CONTAINS clauses and that causes tables scans and the query is very slow.

I'm able to rewrite this using two queries and a temporary table. When I do so, the query executes 10 times faster. But I don't want to do that in the code that creates the query because it is too complex.

Is there an a way to force SQL Server to process the CONTAINS before anything else? I can't force a plan (USE PLAN) because the query is built dynamically and varies a lot.

Note: I have the same problem on SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This bit sounds problematic - "the query is built dynamically and varies a lot" - because it may mean that processing `CONTAINS` first and other conditions afterwards *may not* always be optimal, so even if you do manage to tie the optimizer's hands, it may not have the desired effects.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The only perfect solution would be a fix in the SQL Server optimizer itself. I don't know why it does not figure out that processing the CONTAINS first will be much faster. So, any other solution will not be optimal in all cases. However, I know that in our case processing the CONTAINS first will be faster most of the times. But you are right; I can't guarantee it.

Answer (score 2):

You can signal your intent to the optimiser like this

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM


    WHERE
       CONTAINS
    ) T1
WHERE
   (normal conditions)
```

However, SQL is declarative: you say *what* you want, not *how* to do it. So the optimiser may decide to ignore the nesting above.

You can force the derived table with CONTAINS to be materialised before the classic WHERE clause is applied. I won't guarantee performance.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    (
    SELECT TOP 2000000000
       *
    FROM
       ....
    WHERE
       CONTAINS
    ORDER BY
       SomeID
    ) T1
WHERE
   (normal conditions)
```

Comment: Hmm, nice, I was going to suggest a loop join hint if the CONTAINS results are always known to be small in number, but this is much cleaner, best of both worlds.

Comment: @gbn: If you use a CTE doesn't that **force** evaluation first?

Comment: @Yuck: consider a CTE a macro just like my derived table. That is, I could have used a CTE instead. Same result...

Comment: @gbn: Interesting. I was under the - mistaken apparently - impression that a CTE was more like an implicit temp table than a sub-query.

Comment: @Yuck: it can be when recursive, but for this scenario it's a macro to make your code look better :-)

Comment: @Tao, Can you please post your your loop join hint solution. Although less clean, it might be easier to put in our query builder. Thanks

Comment: I confirm that the `TOP` trick works even if used in `where`. Like `WHERE SomeID IN (SELECT TOP ....)` Don't even need to do the subquery

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with 2 queries without temp tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE contains_criterias
) 
AND further_where_classes
```

Answer (score 0):

As I noted above, this is NOT as clean a way to "materialize" the derived table as the TOP clause that @gbn proposed, but a loop join hint forces an order of evaluation, and has worked for me in the past (admittedly usually with two different tables involved). There are a couple of problems though:

- The query is ugly
- you still don't get any guarantees that the other WHERE parameters don't get evaluated until after the join (I'll be interested to see what you get)

Here it is though, given that you asked:

```
SELECT OriginalTable.XXX
FROM (
    SELECT XXX
    FROM OriginalTable
    WHERE 
        CONTAINS XXX
) AS ContainsCheck
INNER LOOP JOIN OriginalTable 
    ON ContainsCheck.PrimaryKeyColumns = OriginalTable.PrimaryKeyColumns
        AND OriginalTable.OtherWhereConditions = OtherValues
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the answer.